# How to run `chmod` command form script with sudo permissions?

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, sudo, cgi

I want the change the permissions of `/dev/ttyACM0` from a script.

I have tried this command:

```
su -c "chmod -R 777 /dev/ttyACM*" -m "$user".
```

When I execute the script it is asking for a password. I want run this without being prompted for password.

I tried adding an user in `/etc/sudoers`, but it doesn't work.

It is a CGI script. It is not working external requests (i.e. from other IPs).

```
user ALL= (user)  NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/cgi-bin/test.cgi
```

How can I do change the permissions so that anyone can execute the script from other IP addresses?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't said why the sudo solution doesn't work, but troubleshooting sudo is rather onerous. This test line in `/etc/sudoers` worked for me

```
cgiuser ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod -R 777 /tmp/xxx*
```

so give it a try. Your `/etc/sudoers` line would be

```
user ALL = (root) NOPASSWD: /bin/chmod -R 777 /dev/ttyACM*
```

and your script would have

```
/usr/bin/sudo /bin/chmod -R 777 /dev/ttyACM*
```

Just make sure that the script runs as `user`, for a cgi script it's probably `apache` or `www-data`.

PS: The previous answer is just wrong. Provided that you belong to the `sudo` group or otherwise have the privileges, `sudo su -` works perfectly to become root, even if no root password is set.
`sudo -s` is probably better, however. YMMV